# What are these large malloc objects?

Tags: ios, debugging, memory-management

I've been trying to debug my app in Instruments in Xcode, and the memory continually grows with very large malloc objects. I am compiling with ARC.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find where your app allocates memory, switch to the call tree view in Instruments. Use the jump bar to switch to the call tree view. In your screenshot you would click the Statistics button in the jump bar, which is above the statistics in your screenshot.

When you switch to the call tree view, the Call Tree checkboxes that are disabled in your screenshot will be enabled. Selecting the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes will make it easier to find your code in the call tree view and find where your app is creating the large malloc objects.

Comment: Thank you, now I definitely know which code is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Create method to `dealloc` memory which you have assigned

and declare your objects like this,

```
[[[object alloc] init] autorelease];



-(void) dealloc {      
    [object release];
}
```

Comment: But what if it uses arc?